# Date format in knock out js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi all I have formatted the date in knock out js as follow using `moment.js`

`<div data-bind="text: moment(formatDate).format('DD-MMM-YY')"></div>`

but when date is null it is displaying as `invalid date` how can I show empty text here instead of `invalid date`

Comment: User a custom binding handler for your presentation logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an expression within `text`:

```
<div data-bind="
    text: ko.unwrap(formatDate) ? moment(formatDate).format('DD-MMM-YY') : ''
"></div>
```

Or use an [extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html):

```
ko.extenders.formatDate = function(target, format) {
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target,
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target(),
                valueToWrite = !newValue || isNaN(newValue) ? '' : moment(newValue).format(format);

            // only write if it changed
            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                target(valueToWrite);
            } else {
                if (newValue !== current) {
                    target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
    }).extend({notify: 'always'});

    result(target());

    return result;
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
var someDateObservable = ko.observable();
var someDateObservableFormatted = someDateObservable.extend({
    formatDate: 'DD-MMM-YY'
});
```